# Default spring profile?

Tags: spring

To read a Spring profile I use :

```
<beans profile="LOC">
```

I have this property set as a jvm property :

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=LOC
```

Is it possible to use some logic just use the profile "LOC" if it exists and it does not exist use a default profile ?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. What does "use the profile "LOC" if it exists and it does not exist use a default profile?" mean? Do you want to include new beans in the LOC profile, override beans in the 'default' profile, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in spring 3.2, where the ! operator has been introduced:

```
<beans profile="LOC">
    <import resource="LOC.xml"/>
</beans>
<beans profile="!LOC">
    <import resource="default.xml"/>
</beans>
```

LOC.xml will be included when the LOC profile is active. default.xml will be included if LOC is not defined.

The change has been announced here: http://www.springsource.org/node/3563
and the commit is here: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/commit/bcd44f3798ed06c0704d2a3564b8a9735e747e87

Answer (score 2):

If you have a web.xml you can specify it there:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
   <param-value>LOC</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Otherwise you can try to use the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer`. See: http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/spring-31-cool-new-features.html

Is this enough for you?

Comment: Thanks I looked everywhere in our code source until I remembered that the tomcat configuration came from the image we pulled.